# Identifying possibility of interference

Tags: c, real-time, interrupt, multitasking, rtos

In multi tasking environment. If a task has the expression `y = x + x;` is there a possibility of an interrupt(task switching) occurring between the two reads of x.

Comment: short answer is that it's unlikely but possible

Comment: If `x` is an object that is modified concurrently by another thread, and/or asynchronously by a signal handler, and `a` is not atomic or either lock-free atomic or of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` in case of the signal-handler, the behavior is *undefined*.

Comment: On some architectures, it isn't even guaranteed that a single `x` can be fetched with a single atomic instruction (`long long`on a <64-bit architecture, for example). So generally, not even `y = 2 * x` would be thread-safe without locking the variable.

Comment: The above three comments could usefully be elaborated into answers - answers should not be posted as comments.  A legitimate use of comments would be to have explained why the question deserved downvotes - it seems a legitimate question to me - albeit with a somewhat vague title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases a compiler generate code would read x only once since the optimisation is trivial.  In fact it might even translate the operation into a right-shift, equivalent to `x << 1`.  However you cannot guarantee that, and if `x` were declared `volatile` it would necessarily make two reads that will then be uninterruptible between reading of the low-order and high-order words (or vice versa),and in that case the assignment of `y` is also interruptable.

Another issue is that if `x` were not an atomic data type (i.e. could not be read in a single instruction) such as a 32 bit type on a 16 bit target for example, then even if it were a single read, it may be interruptable.

In either case it is only normally a problem if the `x` itself (or `y` in the second case) is shared between contexts (in which case it should also be declared `volatile` so two reads would then be necessary), or if for some reason the timing of the assignment were somehow critical and needed to be entirely deterministic (unlikely).

If `x` is shared and therefore `volatile` but is an atomic type, the simple solution in *this example* is to write the expression `y = x << 1` or `y = x * 2` to ensure that `x` is read only once.  Where `x` is not atomic - you might need to lock the scheduler or disable interrupts (i.e. use a *critical section*), or more selectively protect the access with a mutex for example. For more complex expressions where the expression cannot be reduced to a single reference to the shared variable, simply assigning the variable to a non-shared local temporary variable ensures that it is read just once.  The issue of atomicity still stands.

Answer (score -1):

Here a specific answer for x86 like architectures, used with a traditional scheduler (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler). Have a look at this asm code, generated for x86 by gcc with optimization set to -OS0.

https://godbolt.org/g/AfKTkF

```
int main(void) {
  int y;
  int x = 5;
  y = x + x;
}
```

turns to

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $5, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  #read x
        addl    %eax, %eax      #execute x + x
        movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

As you can see x is only read once, thus implying that even if there WAS a task switch, there would be no second read on x.

---

**Edit:** 
EOL states in the comments that `x` indeed can be read two times, modifying the code above yields following:

```
volatile x = 5;
```

forces the compiler to insert two movl operations (instead of one):

```
movl    -8(%rbp), %edx
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
```

This does not make my first guess wrong though. The compiler would optimize the read access of the variable (if it is a simple type) and remove the second read. The [volatile](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_(Informatik)) keyword forces the compiler to access the latest value in the registers. The first code won't force that read - thus giving a other result in case of thread switches and modification of `x`.

Comment: This only answers for the case of one specific hardware and software combination

Comment: @M.M Given the fact that there is no hardware / software combination stated in the question I assumed a popular and widely used one.
And given the fact that a context switch (http://www.linfo.org/context_switch.html) is always pretty much the same. I can edit the question to state clearly that this is not generally valid. Would this remove the downvote from me?

Comment: Addressing the other downvotes: Could you please Elaborate? I can see that I only cover a special case, it still answers the question from the OP.

Comment: The C standard does *not* guarantee that `x` will only be read once in this expression. In fact, as far as the abstract machine is concerned, `x` is read twice (you can test this by `volatile`-qualifying `x`). If `x` is modified concurrently, the behavior is **undefined**.

Comment: @EOF: That is very true. We shouldn't loose focus though. OP asks if it is possible that a interrupt happens between those two reads. My first suggestion was that - given the code we have - no interrupt can happen as there is going to be only one movl instruction. What happens with x's value is not in our scope. Declaring x volatile will force two read instructions, thus an interrupt is possible between those two. 
Or am I completely stuck on this one?

Comment: @Haini: What a single compiler does for a single platform in a single contrived test is irrelevant, you cannot rely on this. The only reliable thing is to know which guarantees the language gives you. Caching the value of `x` for reuse in the expression is not among the language's guarantees.

Comment: @EOF: I understand your point now, thanks. I was somehow confused by it.

So.. Do you suggest that I incorporate this into my answer or should I remove the answer all along as neither the question nor the answer are well received currently? Thanks for your time and explanation!

Comment: @Haini: I suppose you *could* write an interesting answer to this question. I'd start with explaining what guarantees C gives for this situation (very few), and possibly discuss *why* the compiler is even allowed to reuse the value of `x`, even though the abstract machine would need to load it twice (this gets into the as-if rule and undefined behavior on concurrent access to non-atomic, non-readonly objects).

Comment: While x86 is "*popular and widely used*" in desktop systems with a GPOS, it is less so in applications that might use an RTOS perhaps.  I would not down vote on that basis however - it if fairly clear that this is a specific example of a specific compiler with specific compiler options and a specific instruction set.  How *useful* that is the OP can decide.

Comment: ... Referring to your answer as a "guess" though might weaken your argument.  We should not be "guessing".  Looking at the code the compiler generated is a dangerous way of determining the "rules".  A different compiler, different compiler options, or a different target might produce a different result.